# monitor job failures in a Jenkins and Email alert

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email

I need to write a script to monitor job failures in a Jenkins farm and send an email with a report of the top 5 unstable jobs in the farm.
How can do it?
Is there any plugin available for this requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins mailer plugin can send mails if a build fails. Did you try that ?

[link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mailer)

[image]